# R: count with missing value and other criteria

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I have a simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have two columns, call them `col1` and `col2`.

I'm not sure how to phrase it, but I would like to count rows for which `col1` has a missing value and `col2=="USA'`.

I'm trying `sum(is.na(df$col1),df$col2=="USA")` but it doesn't work.

If that can help, the stata equivalent would be

```
count if col1=="" & col2=="USA"
```

Comment: `df$col1==""` is not the same as `is.na(df$col1)`. Compare empty string vs. `NA`. In general you probably want a logical AND to combine two conditions. `sum(is.na(df$col1) & df$col2 == "USA")`

Comment: Hi Maurits, why do you say it's not the same? When I want to count only missing values sum(is.na(df$col1)) returns me the same result as in stata count if col1=="". It's when I add the second condition that things get messy. I also tried with & instead of comma, but result is the same (it returns NA instead of the true number that I know from stata)

Comment: No, `NA` is *not* the same as an empty string in R. There is no "why". See `?NA` for details. This is an R question, isn't it?

Comment: maybe I'm confused because I'm importing into R a dataset that was originally in Stata: when I do that, empty cells in the original file automatically become NA in R. I will try to understand the distinction, thank you.

Comment: Right I see. Try `sum(is.na(df$col1) & df$col2 == "USA")` if entries are `NA`. If they are empty strings try `sum(df$col1 == "" & df$col2 == "USA")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Chicago", NA, NA, "Melbourne", "NY", NA, NA),
                 col2 = c("USA", "USA", "Australia", "Australia", "USA", "USA", "Australia"))

#       col1      col2
#1   Chicago       USA
#2      <NA>       USA
#3      <NA> Australia
#4 Melbourne Australia
#5        NY       USA
#6      <NA>       USA
#7      <NA> Australia

# Using dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(is.na(col1), col2 == 'USA') %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
#      count
#1     2

# Using base R
sum(is.na(df$col1) & df$col2 == 'USA')
#[1] 2
```